# How to create a non-UTF8 string?

Tags: python

I need to test that my code works for non-UTF8 strings as well. How can I create a non-UTF8 string in Python?

```
str = ?
```

Comment: python version 2 or 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either specify a byte sequence that isn't a valid UTF-8 sequence, or encode into a charset that isn't UTF-8.

```
s1 = 'AB\xfc'
s2 = u'æ'.encode('cp1252')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unicode string with `u"String"` and then encode with any codec other than `utf-8`.

If you are going to directly use the unicode characters in your source file, then you have to explicitly mention the encoding used, as the first line of the program like this.

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
var = u"தமிழ்".encode("iso-8859-15")
print(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about python 2 (you haven't specified) then default encoding is ascii.
So you can just write

```
str = "something"
```

as opposed to unicode string

```
str = u"unicode string"
```

Comment: Technically all ASCII bytestrings are UTF-8 bytestrings as well.